# Firebase multi-path update set a parent node to null

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to use firebase realtime database multi path updates.
However trying to set a parent node to null as below will result on an error.

```
const firebaseUpdate = {}
firebaseUpdate[`user/${uid}`] = null
db.ref().update(firebaseUpdate)
```

> Error: Reference.update failed: First argument contains a path /user/USER_ID 
>       that is ancestor of another path /user/USER_ID/creationTime

I was wondering if there is a way to use multi-path updates in order to set a parent node with multiple children to null.
I assume I could use remove or set function but I'd rather use the multi-path update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message indicates that you're trying to apply two conflicting updates to the database in one operation. As the message says, your update tries to:

1. write to `/user/USER_ID`
2. write to `/user/USER_ID/creationTime`

The second one write is a child of the first one. Since the order of writes in a multi-location is unspecified, it's impossible to say what the outcome of the write operation will be.

If you want to replace any data that currently exists at `/user/USER_ID` with the `creationTime`, you should update it like this:

```
db.ref().update({
  "/user/USER_ID": { creationTime: Date.now() }
})
```

Comment: I only want to set /user/USER_ID path to null. Thanks I was just wondering if I was able to do it using multi path updates

Comment: You are. But the error message indicates that you're trying to perform two conflicting writes, which the server detects and rejects.